# How to fix, Pygame won't go to next lot of text

Tags: pygame, python-3.4

My game is an RPG game text-based game, my problem is I can not get the text to move to the next stage.

I have tried just reading over it and I have fixed a few problems but I can not seem to find what is causing the problem

```
def Text2(self):

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    input_box = pygame.Rect(100, 200, 140, 32)
    input_box2 = pygame.Rect(150, 250, 160, 32)
    color_inactive = pygame.Color('lightskyblue3')
    color_active = pygame.Color('dodgerblue2')
    color = color_inactive
    active = False
    color_inactive2 = pygame.Color('lightskyblue3')
    color_active2 = pygame.Color('dodgerblue2')
    color2 = color_inactive2
    active2 = False
    text = 'You Have woken up in a room! what do you do?'
    Text3 = False
    Text4 = False
    done = False
    mouseClicked = False

    while not done:
        text2 = ''
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                # If the user clicked on the input_box rect.
                if input_box.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    # Toggle the active variable.
                    active = not active
                else:
                    active = False
                if input_box2.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    # Toggle the active variable.
                    active2= not active2
                else:
                    active2 = False
                # Change the current color of the input box.
                color2 = color_active2 if active2 else color_inactive2
                color = color_active if active else color_inactive
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if active:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        print(text)
                        text = 'look around'
                        Text3 = True
                if active2:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        print(text2)
                        text2 = 'go back to sleep'
                        Text4 = True
                        pygame.display.update()
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                        text = text[:-1]
                    else:
                        text += event.unicode
        while Text3:
            clock.tick(120)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        self.Text3()
        while Text4:
            self.Quit()

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        # Render the current text.
        txt_surface = font3.render(text, True, color)
        # Resize the box if the text is too long.
        width = max(200, txt_surface.get_width()+10)
        input_box.w = width
        # Blit the text.
        screen.blit(txt_surface, (input_box.x+5, input_box.y+5))
        # Blit the input_box rect.
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, input_box, 2)
        # Render the current text.
        txt_surface2 = font3.render(text2, True, color2)
        # Resize the box if the text is too long.
        width2 = max(200, txt_surface2.get_width()+10)
        input_box2.w = width2
        # Blit the text2
        screen.blit(txt_surface2, (input_box2.x+5, input_box2.y+5))
        # Blit the input_box rect.
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, input_box2, 2)


        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)
```

So I should be seeing the Text go from "you have woken up in a room what do you do?" to "go back to sleep" and "Look around", instead it displays "you have woken up in a room what do you do?" twice then you can no longer high light the box.

Answer (score 0):

The code presented in the question does not produce the specified error (it does not include the text "Look around", for example).  The use of states `Text2`, `Text3` etc. along with the strings `text3` et.al. make the code difficult to understand.

If I may suggest an improvement: please consider creating a data structure to hold your game "World". Then establish a set of commands for moving around (e.g.: "look", "north", "south" ... ) and interacting with objects (e.g.: "get", "drop", "fight", "extinguish" ...)

With a clear world and command layout, it makes the code much easier to write.

A World Location can just be a unique identifier and a description:

```
locations = { "start" : [ "You have woken up in a room", { "east":"hall1" } ],  \
              "hall1" : [ "You are in the hallway", { "west":"start", "south": "hall2" } ],  \
              "hall2" : [ "You are at the end of the hall", { "north":"hall1" } ],  \
             }
```

In a trivial example, each entry in the `locations` dictionary contains a description and a list of directions & destinations.  So if the player is in "hall1", the direction-list includes entries for "west" and "south".  The data itself defines what the place can do in each area.

Put the player somewhere:

```
player_location = "start"
```

Commands like "look" simply become:

```
description = locations[ player_location ][0]
setPlayerText( description )
```

Commands like "go" check the available directions, and then adjust the player.

```
exits = locations[ player_location ][1]
if ( direction_word in exits ):
    player_location = exits[ direction_word ]
else:
    setPlayerText( "No exit %s" % direction_word )
```

The commands from the player just modify a cursor through the data.  This frees the complicated GUI from also having to know how to operate on the game locations.  This removes the necessity for the code to have `text1`, `text2`, etc.

This World data structure could easily be extended to include a list of object-ids at the location, which reference another dictionary of player-objects (e.g.: "silver key", "pitch torch", ... ) that can do things.

A location `class` would probably be useful, but you could get something working with simple dictionaries and lists.